# SPARK_HOME not found if UDF defined and used in imported package

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, emr, apache-spark-sql

Spark executor shoots back the following error when I import code from a different file in which UDF is defined and used, I got the following

```
"/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1486510313225_0004/container_1486510313225_0004_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 48, in launch_gateway
    SPARK_HOME = os.environ["SPARK_HOME"]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/os.py", line 633, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME'
```

I'm using AWS EMR. The version is `emr-5.1.0`. It has applications: `Spark 2.0.1, Ganglia 3.7.2, Hive 2.1.0`

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The SPARK_HOME environment variable is only set on the master instance, since Spark is only installed on the master instance. It would not make sense for SPARK_HOME to be set on any other instance because it is not installed there. Your error is occurring in a YARN container, meaning that it is running on a core/task instance rather than the master instance.

Comment: What is it that this library is doing, and why would it need to know SPARK_HOME?